# match PHP and CryptoJS output

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot find the solution to the reverse of the linked question, and have tested it the same way.  php and javascript are giving different values because of certain characters.  The below sample code gives different outputs, but without the appended character 253 javascript and php match.  How do I modify my javascript code to give a match to the php code?

```
    $test = 'test'.chr(253);
    $key = 'key';
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha512',$test,$key,true);
    $sign = base64_encode($sign);
    var_dump($sign);

/* 
oMb9XiT7Y18wYJ7m0kOaIebZrS7eY+/odXmHLq5xPjRVbNfdcwBYQGycRKQ0n7EgqFmF+Ul3oucJHH2AK/IYLw==
*/

    var test = 'test'+String.fromCharCode(253);
    var key = 'key';
    var sign = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(test,key);
    var sign = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(sign);
    Console.log(sign);

/*
rQ5cGz9eMTKQpA3a8zzzNmwoXatSmOiBQBtV1gqs7oAGqn6XMwxq0Ww0tmtVbmpqlEVJ9xeYFMzka749c5vIvQ==
*/
```

[Why HMAC sha256 return different value on PHP & Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941233/why-hmac-sha256-return-different-value-on-php-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link you included in your question. CryptoJS interprets strings as UTF-8. The character `ý` is two bytes in UTF-8 `chr(195).chr(189)`, so your JavaScript is equivalent to hashing the PHP string `'test'.chr(195).chr(189)`.

To get the PHP result in JavaScript, you will need to parse the array to a Cypto.lib.WordArray using the encoding you want (Latin1) manually instead so that it doesn't assume UTF-8:

```
var test = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse( 'test'+String.fromCharCode(253) );
// oMb9XiT7Y18wYJ7m0kOaIebZrS7eY+/odXmHLq5xPjRVbNfdcwBYQGycRKQ0n7EgqFmF+Ul3oucJHH2AK/IYLw==
```